# Выровнять начало строк по вертикали

Tags: html, css

Просмотрите код и скриншоты. Вопрос в следующем: когда тексту не хватает места и происходит перенос строки, она начинается от левого края, под чеком. Мне нужно чтобы она располагалась ровно под началом первой строки. Пробовал оборачивать текст в параграф и играться с `text-indent`, `margin-left:-20px`. Но т.к. текст принимает блочный тип он опускается на строку ниже от чекбокса. Если обернуть текст в `<ul>` и убрать все отступы чекбокс "прилипает к нижней строке. Скорее всего вопрос глупый, но мне никак не придумать адекватное решение, без использования `&nbsp;` и позиционирования элементов. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

```html
<div class="answer_check">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label style="" class="area_box">
 провести и оформить инструктажи по технике безопасности и производству работ
 </label>
</div>
```

[image: Суть проблемы]
[image: Списком <ul>]
[image: <p> + отрицательный indent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.answer_check: {display:table;}
.answer_check input, .answer_check label {display: table-cell;}
```

Само собой, это в стилях.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется нужно использовать табличную верстку, вот вариант с использованием блоков, хотя можно всё просто в таблицу было затолкать и выставить таблице border="0"

```css
.answer_check {
  display: table-row;
}

.answer_check .column {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="answer_check">
  <div class="column"><input type="checkbox"/></div>
  <div class="column"><label style="" class="area_box">Провести и оформить инструктажи по технике безопасности и производству работ. Провести и оформить инструктажи по технике безопасности и производству работ</label></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Оберни текст параграфом и `input-у` задай `float:left;`

```html
<div class="answer_check">
  <input type="checkbox" style="float:left;" />
  <label style="" class="area_box">
 <p>провести и оформить инструктажи по технике безопасности и производству работровести и оформить инструктажи по технике безопасности и производству работ</p>
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня почему то, это привело к тому что параграф уехал на следующую строчку от чекбокса

Comment: Хозяин-барин... Тебе видней